# Looping through an object only returns the first object

Tags: javascript, for-loop, object, array.prototype.map

I am trying to reshape some data to be used in a table. To do this I am mapping over an array and then looping over an object inside of it to create a new object with the data I want in it. The issue Im having is if the object contains more than one object inside of it I only get a new object for the first item.

I am trying to get a new object for each of the objects held inside `changedProperties`

Can anyone help? / Explain?

Here is a working example:

```js
const MOCK_DATA = [
  {
    triggeredByID: "d5ae18b7eb6f",
    triggeredByName: "name",
    changedProperties: {
      LastName: {
        __oldValue: "Mallory",
        __newValue: "Mallorie",
      },
      Suffix: {
        __oldValue: "DO",
        __newvValue: "NP",
      },
    },
    createdAt: "2022-06-01T10:20:21.329337652Z",
  },
  {
    triggeredByID: "d5ae18b7eb6f",
    triggeredByName: "John",
    changedProperties: {
      State: {
        __oldValue: ["TX", "AL"],
        __newValue: ["TX", "AL", "FL"],
      },
      City: {
        __oldValue: "Austin",
        __newValue: "San Antonio",
      },
    },
    createdAt: "2022-06-01T10:20:21.329337652Z",
  },
];

const changedProperties = MOCK_DATA.map((item, idx) => {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(item.changedProperties)) {
      return {
        field: key,
        old: item.changedProperties[key].__oldValue,
        new: item.changedProperties[key].__newValue,
        name: item.triggeredByName,
        createdAt: item.createdAt,
      };
    }
  });
  
  console.log(changedProperties)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you return inside a for-loop, its scoped to the function. Meaning you will return from the entire function on the first iteration of your loop. Try this instead:

```
const changedProperties = MOCK_DATA.map((item, idx) => {
   return Object.entries(item.changedProperties).map(([key, value]) => {
      return {
        field: key,
        old: item.changedProperties[key].__oldValue,
        new: item.changedProperties[key].__newValue,
        name: item.triggeredByName,
        createdAt: item.createdAt,
      };
    }
  });
  
  console.log(changedProperties)
```

Comment: Can you explain an alternative to returning inside the for loop? Your answer is returning an array of undefined values for me :/

Comment: You need to put `return ` before `Object.entries`

Comment: @asportnoy can you explain?

Comment: See the edit to the answer.

Comment: This is super helpful. It seems a little messy but it works. Im not sure of a better way to do this. But thank you for your help!